# Unwrap paragraphs while deleting spaces

Tags: linux, sed, tr

I've reached a frustrating end trying to figure out how to change the formatting of a file using sed, tr, etc.  I'm sure there's some right answer to do what I want to do, I just don't know what it is.

Here's my problem.  I have a data file that looks like this:

```
   8587  812.700  152.791  12.7410   0.0372  99.9999   9.9999  12.2520   0.0436  99.9999   9.9999  99.9999   9.9999  99.9999   9.9999
                           99.9999   9.9999  99.9999   9.9999  99.9999   9.9999  99.9999   9.9999  99.9999   9.9999  99.9999   9.9999
                           99.9999   9.9999  99.9999   9.9999  99.9999   9.9999  13.1942   0.0589  99.9999   9.9999  99.9999   9.9999
                           99.9999   9.9999  12.9601   0.1323  99.9999   9.9999   1.0337   0.3166
```

And I want to turn it into a single line.  There are about 10,000 of these blocks in each file.  I think that I want to cut out any newline characters followed by 26 spaces, which would do the job and leave the newline in place for the next block.

So, are there any handy linux tools available to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cuts newline if its followed by `26` spaces:

```
awk '{printf "%s",(/^                          /?$0:RS $0)}' file
```

Would you also like to remove the `26` spaces?

```
awk '{printf "%s",(/^                          /?$0:RS $0)}' file | awk '{gsub(/                          /,"")}1'
   8587  812.700  152.791  12.7410   0.0372  99.9999   9.9999  12.2520   0.0436  99.9999   9.9999  99.9999   9.9999  99.9999   9.9999 99.9999   9.9999  99.9999   9.9999  99.9999   9.9999  99.9999   9.9999  99.9999   9.9999  99.9999   9.9999 99.9999   9.9999  99.9999   9.9999  99.9999   9.9999  13.1942   0.0589  99.9999   9.9999  99.9999   9.9999 99.9999   9.9999  12.9601   0.1323  99.9999   9.9999   1.0337   0.3166
```

---

Another example:
Remove newline and 6 space, if next line starts with 6 spaces.

```
cat file
data here
      more data
      not here
but this is new line
so i this
```

Here is all in one `awk` without giving blank line at the top, and correct ending.

```
awk '{split($0,a,"     ")} NR==1 {a[2]=$0} {printf "%s",(/^      /||NR==1?a[2]:RS $0)}END{print ""}' file
data here more data not here
but this is new line
so i this
```

---

Rewritten code:

```
awk '{printf "%s",(gsub(/ {5}/,"")||NR==1?$0:RS $0)} END {print ""}' file
data here more data not here
but this is new line
so i this
```

if `{5}` (number of spaces) does not work, try add `--re-interval` to your `awk` command, or just use the number of spaces you need.

Comment: You can use `/^ {26}/` to match 26 spaces at the beginning of the line.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler True, but not for `gnu awk` `3.x` where you need to add option `--re-interval` or `--posix`

Comment: Magnificent.  The second option, removing the spaces, is exactly what I needed.  Way faster and easier than the fortran code I was kludging together.

Comment: Curious.  I agree that GNU `awk` 3.1.7 does not handle the regex with `{26}` by default.  The BSD `awk` (from Mac OS X) does.  It's hard to prove or disprove when that was made available as a feature, but I'm surprised indeed that it is not in `gawk` 3.x as standard.

Comment: `--re-interval` was first introduced in gawk 3.0 and RE interval support became the default in 4.0. See http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Feature-History. I contributed $5 to get Arnold to put that section in the manual so please read it :-)! btw, don't use `--posix` unless you have a very specific purpose in mind as it disables all other gawk goodies (e.g. gensub()).

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the enlightening comments :)

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ gawk -vRS='^$' -vORS= '{gsub(/\n {26}/,"")}1' file
   8587  812.700  152.791  12.7410   0.0372  99.9999   9.9999  12.2520   0.0436  99.9999   9.9999  99.9999   9.9999  99.9999   9.9999 99.9999   9.9999  99.9999   9.9999  99.9999   9.9999  99.9999   9.9999  99.9999   9.9999  99.9999   9.9999 99.9999   9.9999  99.9999   9.9999  99.9999   9.9999  13.1942   0.0589  99.9999   9.9999  99.9999   9.9999 99.9999   9.9999  12.9601   0.1323  99.9999   9.9999   1.0337   0.3166
```